# Get name of function in javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo

How can I get the function name inside a function in Javascript?

Specifically in Dojo, as this doesn't seem to do the job

```
arguments.callee.caller
```

Comment: arguments.callee.name is what you're looking for, but you should use hard-coded names if you want to be future-friendly.

Comment: Thanks Dan,arguments.callee.name is undefined. I want to avoid hard coded values. I do have a function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dojo, if the function is a method of a class declared through dojo/_base/declare you can get it through :

```
arguments.callee.nom
```

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/declare.html

> Every method mixed in by dojo/declare() or safeMixin() is annotated: a special property called nom is added. It contains a name of the method in question and used by inherited() and getInherited() to deduce the name of a superclass method. See [safeMixin()](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/declare.html#safemixin) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Whether `arguments.callee.name` is defined or not depends on how the function was defined. It will be defined if the function was defined as [Named function expression](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/). Otherwise, you will not have this information.

Comment: Thanks for your response piokuc. I declared my function as follows
setmain: function () {...}
Its in dojo

Comment: That `setmain` function does not have a name. You can give it a name after the `function` keyword if you want it to have a name: `setmain: function setmain() {...}`